# mvc action method calls begin form method even if it returns json to another action method

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

Hi I am Currently Working On MVC Razor. here is the scenario. can anyone have a solution? I have a web grid in BeginForm.

```
 @using(Html.BeginForm("AllocationOnlyEdit", "AllocationModel", FormMethod.Post, new {
  block = @Model.block
 })) {
  if (Model != null) {
   var grid = new WebGrid(rowsPerPage: Model.RecordsPerPage);
   grid.Bind(Model.AllocModelsListView, autoSortAndPage: false, rowCount: Model.NumberOfRecords); < div class = "wrap" >
    < div id = "gridContent" >
    @grid.GetHtml(
     htmlAttributes: new {
      id = "gdvsearch"
     },
     fillEmptyRows: false,
     tableStyle: "mGrid",
     columns: new [] {
      grid.Column(header: null, canSort: false, format: @ < text > < input id = "ChkDelete_@item.AllocId"
        onclick = "javascript: DeleteCheckBox(this)"
        name = "ChkDelete_@item.AllocId"
        class = "delete-chkbox"
        type = "checkbox"
        value = "@item.AllocId" / > < /text>),
        grid.Column("AllocYear", header: "Year", format: @ < input name = "AllocYear_@item.AllocId"
         id = "AllocYear"
         type = "text"
         style = "font-weight:bold;width:50px;"
         value = "@item.AllocYear"
         disabled = "disabled"
         title = "@item.AllocYear"
         class = "editY-mode" / > ),

        grid.Column("AllocPercentage", header: "Percentage", format: @ < input name = "AllocPercentage_@item.AllocId"
         id = "AllocPercentage_@item.AllocId"
         type = "text"
         style = "font-weight:bold;width:50px;"
         value = "@item.AllocPercentage"
         disabled = "disabled"
         title = "@item.AllocPercentage"
         class = "editPer-mode" / > ),
        grid.Column("LocationDesc", header: "Location", format: @ < input name = "LocationDesc_@item.AllocId"
         id = "LocationDesc_@item.AllocId"
         type = "text"
         style = "font-weight:bold;width:50px;"
         value = "@item.LocationDesc"
         disabled = "disabled"
         title = "@item.LocationDesc"
         class = "editPer-mode" / > )
```

The grid performs multiple operations (Add/Update/delete) Simultaneously on same click. So the below javascript loops and calls action method for all grid rows that are to be edited/added/deleted.

```
  $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 url: '@Url.Action("DeleteAndSaveAtSameTimeModels")',
 data: {
  "AllocId": AllocId,
  "Allocpercentage": Allocpercentage,
  "sumtrans": sumtrans,
  "tempsumtrancs": tempsumtrancs,
  "Location": Location,
  "rowCount": rowCount
 },
 dataType: "json",
 beforeSend: function() {},
 success: function(data) {
  debugger;
  tempsumtrancs++;
  if (data.sumtrans == tempsumtrancs) {
   window.location.href = data.result;
  }
 }
});
```

if 3 rows are to be deleted and 1 row is to be added, it should call action method "DeleteAndSaveAtSameTimeModels" 4 times, then call default route , i.e Search ActionMethod and give back updated grid.

But what it does is calls BeginForm action Method "AllocationOnlyEdit", and blows off.
the action method returns,

```
return Json(new { ok = true, AllocId = AllocId, y = y, newRows = newRows, sumtrans = sumtrans, tempsumtrancs = tempsumtrancs, result = Url.Action("AllocationModelSearch", objAllocationModels) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that your save button is inside the form and when you click the button it is doing the normal form submit behavior. You should prevent the default form submit behavior before making the ajax call. You may use the jQuery `preventDefault` method to do so.

```
$(function(){
  $("#YourButtonId").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();   // This line does it !
     //Now continue with your ajax code here
     // $.ajax({});
  });
});
```

Also i suggest using POST instead of GET as GET has a limitation on how much data it can pass via the querystring.

Comment: Thanks.. I tried the above code and it worked for me. But when i promoted the code to server it dint work as expected. The delete operation deleted all the records instead of updating few and deleted on checked items. The server configurations are same as development system.

Comment: Your original question was why it is posting to `AllocationOnlyEdit` action instead of posting to the one you mentioned in the ajax code. Now you are asking a totally different question. I don't know what your code does in the server side and you haven't show in the question. Please post a new question with relevant code. **Do not ask new questions in  comments to answers**.